# Problema con JWT Python

Tags: python, post, flask, jwt

Tengo el siguiente código, implementado en Flask Python3, trate de limpiarlo y dejar lo necesario para que se comprenda el inconveniente.

```
from config import SECRET_KEY
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Blueprint
import hashlib 
import bcrypt
from app import db, ma
from marshmallow import fields
from app.users.models import User, user_schema 
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import jwt

logins = Blueprint('login', __name__, url_prefix='/login')
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires')

logins.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    nameUser=request.json['nameUser']
    passwordUser=request.json['passwordUser'].encode('utf8')

    token=jwt.encode({'user':nameUser,'exp' :datetime.datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)},SECRET_KEY)

    return jsonify ({'token': token.decode('utf-8')})
```

La idea es capturar el `nameUser` y `passwordUser`, despues de haberlo comparado con la base de datos(parte omitida en el codigo que colgue aqui), generar el token.

El inconveniente que al hacer el `Post` en Postman con los siguientes datos

```
{
    "nameUser" :"PeterLemo",
    "passwordUser":"peterpan"
  }
```

Flask, me lanza el siguiente error de la librería JWT:

```
Module 'jwt' has no 'encode' member
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos módulos JWT y PyJWT.

Revisa si tienes ambos instalados o solo el JWT.
Desinstala y prueba con PyWJT, lo más seguro es que al importar estás llamando la librería incorrecta.

```
pip uninstall JWT
pip install PyWJT
```